# SQLAlchemy: Multiple tables and joins, duplicate rows

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, duplicates, multiple-tables

[I feel that this is maybe / for sure (?) a duplicate, however, I've searched all day long to find a solution for this and it seems I can't get it working the way I would like to by myself.]

In MySQL, I've got three tables, named ecordov (A), ecordovadr (B) and ecrgposvk (C).
I've got one key linking all these; in (A) there is one row per key, in (B) and (C) there might be multiple rows per key, so, without being an expert in these questions, I think these are one-to-many relations.

I've read the SQLAlchemy docs and set up my tables like this:

```
class Ecordov(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'ecordov'

    oovkey = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    oovorder = Column(BIGINT)
    ecordovadr = relationship('Ecordovadr')
    ecrgposvk = relationship('Ecrgposvk')


class Ecordovadr(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'ecordovadr'

    ooakey = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    ooaname1 = Column(VARCHAR)
    ooaorder = Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey('ecordov.oovorder'))


class Ecrgposvk(Base):

   __tablename__ = 'ecrgposvk'

   rgkey = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
   rgposvalue = Column(DOUBLE)
   rgposordnum = Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey('ecordov.oovorder'))
```

[So, as you see, the `ForeignKeys` aren't the `primary_key(s)`, not really sure if this is a problem? However, I can't change the structure of the database.]

My sample query looks like:

```
jobs = session.query(Ecordov, func.group_concat(Ecordovadr.ooaname1.op('ORDER BY')(text('ecordovadr.ooatype, ecordovadr.ooarank separator "{}"'))).label('ooaname1')).outerjoin(Ecordovadr).filter(Ecordov.oovorder.like('75289')).group_by(Ecordov.oovorder)
```

gets evaluated to:

```
SELECT ecordov.oovkey AS ecordov_oovkey, ecordov.oovorder AS ecordov_oovorder, group_concat(ecordovadr.ooaname1 ORDER BY ecordovadr.ooatype, ecordovadr.ooarank separator "{}") AS ooaname1 
FROM ecordov LEFT OUTER JOIN ecordovadr ON ecordov.oovorder = ecordovadr.ooaorder 
WHERE ecordov.oovorder LIKE '75289'
GROUP BY ecordov.oovorder
```

and gives me the following:

```
for x in jobs:
    x.ooaname1

u'Sorbe priv.{}Lebensn\xe4he GmbH'
```

which is my desired outcome.

However, after joining the second table as well, regardless if using an inner- or outerjoin, via, for example, this:

```
jobs = session.query(Ecordov, func.group_concat(Ecordovadr.ooaname1.op('ORDER BY')(text('ecordovadr.ooatype, ecordovadr.ooarank separator "{}"'))).label('ooaname1')).outerjoin(Ecordovadr).outerjoin(Ecrgposvk).filter(Ecordov.oovorder.like('75289')).group_by(Ecordov.oovorder)
```

which gets evaluated to:

```
SELECT ecordov.oovkey AS ecordov_oovkey, ecordov.oovorder AS ecordov_oovorder, group_concat(ecordovadr.ooaname1 ORDER BY ecordovadr.ooatype, ecordovadr.ooarank separator "{}") AS ooaname1 
FROM ecordov LEFT OUTER JOIN ecordovadr ON ecordov.oovorder = ecordovadr.ooaorder LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrgposvk ON ecordov.oovorder = ecrgposvk.rgposordnum 
WHERE ecordov.oovorder LIKE '75289'
GROUP BY ecordov.oovorder
```

gives me:

```
for x in jobs:
    x.ooaname1

u'Sorbe priv.{}Sorbe priv.{}Sorbe priv.{}Lebensn\xe4he GmbH{}Lebensn\xe4he GmbH{}Lebensn\xe4he GmbH'
```

So, the data is tripled now. I've read in other threads about this topic that this is to be expected, especially when using the same `ForeignKey` for multiple tables.

But I need this data "like before", which means just one entry, instead of three. I've tried using distinct() but without success so far.

Could someone please point me into one direction, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance and all the best!

Comment: Where did you try to use `distinct`? Have you tried `...group_concat(Ecordovard.ooaname1.distinct().op(...)...)`?

Comment: Hi van, thanks a ton for your comment! The way you described works indeed. I've used .distinct(all) at the very end of my query. However, in my specific situation, I've just realized now, that using .distinct() gives me wrong results, because, in some cases, there might be the same name at various positions of the grouped row. The jobs in question are about pickup and delivery, and some jobs do include the same company twice, for example if you pickup at their place, go to another place and then back to the starting point. I've found a workaround now by using two queries, which maybe isn't...

Comment: ... the best performance wise, however, I think, there isn't a different solution for this. If this is not true, just give me a hint. Thanks again!

Comment: Still, I would like to know how to solve this problem properly...just thought about, selecting the primary keys explicitly and using .distinct() on them?

Comment: I don't think I've understood the role of the 3 tables, names do not help me (I guess for you they are ok!!). A few questions, is `oovorder` unique, even if it is not primary key? `oovkey` would be a "technical" pk then, while `oovorder` would be functional? For the example you are posting, `ecordov.oovorder LIKE '75289'`, how many registers are there in each of the 3 tables?

Comment: Hi lrnzcig. thanks for your comment. I try to clarify: I didn't set up the db, nor am I able to alter the structure, and yeah, the table names might be confusing or not really meaningful. `oovorder` is unique in the table `ecordov`, and not unique in `ecordovadr` and `ecrgposvk`, see the very beginning of this thread. Regarding your last question: In the table `ecordov` there is one register, in the other two tables there might be multiple, at least two. Does this help?